# Automatic tracking for new worktree branch

Tags: git, git-worktree

Is it possible to create a new worktree with a new branch `<branch>` and immediately set up tracking to "the" remote? I can do it by explicitly pushing the branch with `--set-upstream`:

```
git worktree add worktrees/<branch>
cd worktrees
git push --set-upstream origin <branch>
```

Is there any way to do this with one git command (the `cd` part is not important), similar to what can be done if the branch already exists at the remote:

```
git worktree add --track -b <branch> worktrees/<branch> origin/<branch>
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no: `git worktree add` does not have that extra bit of mechanism.

This is not exactly tragic, since you can just create the branch in the current working tree, run the `git push --set-upstream`, and then do the `git worktree add`.  Make it a fancy alias if you like, or write a few lines of sh/bash script.  The `git push` step can be run from *any* working tree.